# Android checking all the friends in Facebook FriendPicker sample program

Tags: android, facebook, web-services, friend

I want to know how to select all the friends in Facebook's FriendPicker sample program. I added a 'select all' button in Pickerfragment class. But i couldn't able to find the way to check all the friends.

Comment: Do you want achieve it using Facebook API or via intent ?

Comment: I want to do it by intent

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi I implemented FacebookFriendPicker but for some reason it gives me only my friends that have the same app installed (app I implemented FB SDK in). Is it possible to make it a list with all my friends? The thing is I need to choose which friends to invite to join my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to do it in Friend Picker sample program.
Simply I used graph api to get friends list and listed in list view with a checkbox next to friend's name.

And I added a button that checks all the friends. When I press the button it will iterate over all the friends and checks them.

The idea is pretty simple.

I can't post my code.

I hope you can get some sample programs to get it done.

Ask me if you need more help.

Comment: @m1sk You just try what I said :-) I will guide you, if you get stuck in something.

Comment: it just that this is my first android project, so I dont really know what im doing. thanks alot anyway.

Comment: Oops.. I'm sorry buddy.. I should not show my code.. You just try to start. There are tons of tutorials available if you follow my idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "name, picture");
    JSONObject jsonFrends = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/friends", params));
```

Comment: You can also try this :                                               https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/BaseRequestListener.java

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way :

> ```
>   Intent m_fb=getOpenFacebookIntent(m_context);             
>     startActivity(m_fb);
> ```

Method `getOpenFacebookIntent()` is as below:

> ```
>  public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {
>        try {
>         context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
>     return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/<userid>/fans"));
>           } catch (Exception e) {
>        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/abc.xyz"));
>        }
>     }
> ```

You can use Official Facebook App with Intent listed [HERE](http://www.kanatorn.info/2012/01/03/open-facebook-official-app-with-intent-android/).

Comment: Have you ever run the FriendPicker sample program in Facebook sdk.

Comment: Yes i have also tried to FriendsPicker using facebook sdk also.

Comment: I want to 'select all the friends' (check all the friends) in a single click in that FriendPicker project.

Comment: You need to create your custom listview layout and in that you need to inflate the list of friends which you get and manage the selection on the checkbox click. You can achieve it using Facebook SDK effectively.